# Попытка применть Modin[Dask] к рабочему проекту - провал при чтении файла pd.read_csv()

Tags: python

Есть работающий проект.
Захотелось ускорить работу ввиду чтения 1+ Гб csv файлов и всяких там `groupby() + apply()`.  Реклама, обещавшая [заменить всего одну строчку](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), привлекла.
Установил с нуля все нужные пакеты в Anaconda / Python 3.9.12.   Устанавливал только Dask, чтоб иметь больше определенности на всякий случай.

Запускаю и вот:

```
    UserWarning: Dask execution environment not yet initialized. Initializing...
To remove this warning, run the following python code before doing dataframe operations:

    from distributed import Client

    client = Client()


    2022-06-06 13:00:20,340 - distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory 'D:\\OD\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Chud_Amaz\\Soft_in_dev\\moduled_way_OOP\\dask-worker-space\\worker-75ktabxn', purging
    2022-06-06 13:00:20,365 - distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory 'D:\\OD\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Chud_Amaz\\Soft_in_dev\\moduled_way_OOP\\dask-worker-space\\worker-97o0hmer', purging
    2022-06-06 13:00:20,370 - distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory 'D:\\OD\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Chud_Amaz\\Soft_in_dev\\moduled_way_OOP\\dask-worker-space\\worker-ck5pxauy', purging
    2022-06-06 13:00:20,377 - distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory 'D:\\OD\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Chud_Amaz\\Soft_in_dev\\moduled_way_OOP\\dask-worker-space\\worker-qswh4ton', purging
    2022-06-06 13:00:20,386 - distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory 'D:\\OD\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Chud_Amaz\\Soft_in_dev\\moduled_way_OOP\\dask-worker-space\\worker-vmsc68w6', purging
    2022-06-06 13:00:20,390 - distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory 'D:\\OD\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Chud_Amaz\\Soft_in_dev\\moduled_way_OOP\\dask-worker-space\\worker-ys_mgy6k', purging
    OD ---> Cant read csv D:\_\OD\AD__OD_04.06.22\AD__RET.csv. Error is index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File D:\OD\OneDrive\Projects\Chud_Amaz\Soft_in_dev\moduled_way_OOP\izi_report_main_foldered.py:108 in <module>
    main_foldered()

  File D:\OD\OneDrive\Projects\Chud_Amaz\Soft_in_dev\moduled_way_OOP\izi_report_main_foldered.py:81 in main_foldered
    assert False, "Bad input files"

AssertionError: Bad input files
```

Поскольку я не понимаю, что от меня хочет Dask,  хотел спросить  -  что бы это могло быть?
Ну то есть все работало. Добавил в модули такое:

```
try:
    import modin.pandas as pd
except:
    import pandas as pd
```

И - меня обматерили. Подскажите -  куда бежать?
И - да. У меня Windows10, AMD.

***Ну то есть , кратко вопрос звучит так:***

После установки `modin[dask]` работающий код выдает ошибку:

```
Error is index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Сам `read_csv()`  с такими параметрами:

```
            readed_into_df = pd.read_csv(
                str(file_path),
                skiprows=skiprows_list,
                sep=separator,
                encoding=en_cod_,
                thousands=",",  # TODO: chek it
                on_bad_lines="skip",
                usecols=columns_dtype.keys(),
                dtype=columns_dtype,
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Часть ответа нашел. Может, кому понадобится.

Dask `read_csv` и натуральный `read_csv` из `pandas` по разному обрабатывают параметр `skiprows`.  В моем случае

```
skiprows=skiprows_list,
```

там может быть перечень пропускаемых номеров строк - `skiprows_list`. И в частном случае - пустой список, который  `pandas` просто не пропускает строк  и молча работает.   `Dask` же падает. И даже если подставить туда число скажем 0, падает тоже. Он ухитряется на него что-то делить...

Правда как выяснилось, они по разному обрабатывают несоответствие типов и понятие "пропустить ошибочную строку".  Изучение продолжается )

**Дополнено**
Как оказалось, я нашел-нарвался на [ошибку в `modin`](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/4543).  Оформлен [запрос на устранение бага](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/pull/4544).  Жду релиза )